# Common lisp integer to hex conversion

Tags: decimal, common-lisp, hex

Is there a similar function to (parse-integer "ff" :radix 16) that will take me back the other way?  If I have the int 255 how do I convert it to the string ff?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
(write-to-string 255 :base 16)
```

Answer (score 18):

You can also use [`format`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_format.htm) with the [`~X`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_format.htm) radix designator:

```
CL-USER> (format t "~X" 255)
FF
NIL
```

To get the leading `0x` and a minimum width of, say, four padded with zeros, use

```
CL-USER> (format t "0x~4,'0X" 255)
0x00FF
NIL
```

To force the digits from 10 to 15 to be lowercase, use the [*case conversion* directive](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_cha.htm) `~(` as follows:

```
CL-USER> (format t "0x~(~4,'0x~)" 255)
0x00ff
NIL
```