# Convert hexadecimal number to hexadecimal number presentation in common lisp

Tags: format, common-lisp, numbers

I'm trying to convert hexadecimal number to hexadecimal number presentation.

for example is below.

```
CL-USER> (foo 0D)
#x0D
```

Should i use macro function?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521509/common-lisp-integer-to-hex-conversion

Comment: Mean what i said macro function is macros.(defmacro)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0D is a symbol (by default). Get its name with SYMBOL-NAME as a string. Use PARSE-INTEGER with :RADIX 16 to get the number.

If you don't have any reason for it, representing hex numbers as symbols is nothing I would do.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you want to format a number as a hexadecimal string? If so, you would want something like this: `(format nil "~x" #x0D)`

Comment: I don't understand what you're looking for. Can you try to be more explicit?

Comment: sorry~. I misunderstood your answer. Thank you very much Gabe.

Answer (score 0):

As phrased your question makes no sense.  There is no such thing as a "hexadecimal number"; "hexadecimal" is the name of a number-presentation system.  In your example, the input appears to be a symbol, as Rainer says, but not every such "hexadecimal" is a symbol.  Presumably you want the output of (foo 10) to be #x10, and here the input is a number.  So if the input is interpreted by the Lisp reader as a (base-10) number, then it should be converted to the number you would get if reread base 16.

Another point that Rainer overlooked is that if 0D is understood as a symbol, then (foo 0D) would cause an UNBOUND-VARIABLE error.  You would have to write (foo '0D) to make 0D an input to foo.

On the output side, I don't think there is any native Lisp object that prints as "#x..." . If you want numbers to print in base 16, then you bind *print-base* to 16, but you won't see any sharpsign-x in front of it.

That suggests a somewhat different approach to your problem.  We define a new datatype that *does* print starting with #x, and have foo construct such an object:

```
(defstruct (pseudo-hex (:print-object pseudo-hex-print))
  thing)

(defun pseudo-hex-print (h srm)
   (format srm "#x~a" (pseudo-hex-thing h)))

(defun foo (x)
   (make-pseudo-hex :thing x))
```

Now we get the following:

```
cl-user(162): (foo 38)
#x38
cl-user(163): (foo '0D)
#x0D
```

I have a funny feeling this is not what Rafael was asking!